# Getting multiple inputs and validating them c++

Tags: c++, validation, input, enums

I have multiple enums which act like settings to the program. I want to take them from the user input one by one and keep asking for user input on a certain setting until a valid input has been given, but I feel like my approach repeats a lot of code. Is there a better/smarter way to do this?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

enum Input1 {Type1 = 1, Type2 = 2, Type3 = 3, Type4 = 4};
enum Input2 {Type11 = 5, Type22 = 17};

bool validate_input(Input1 input1, Input2 input2 = Type11) {
  if(input1 != Type1 && input1 != Type2 && input1 != Type3 && input1 != Type4) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if(input2 != Type11 && input2 != Type22) {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  int iInput1, iInput2, iInput3;
  Input1 eInput1;
  Input2 eInput2;
  bool return_val;
  
  do {
    std::cout << "Select option: 1. 2. 3. 4.";
    std::cin >> iInput1;

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    eInput1 = (Input1) iInput1;

    return_val = validate_input(eInput1);
    if (!return_val) {
      std::cout << "Invalid input!\n";
    }
  } while (!return_val);
  
  do {
    std::cout << "Select option: 1. 2.";
    std::cin >> iInput2;

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    eInput2 = (Input2) iInput2;

    return_val = validate_input(eInput1, eInput2);
    if (!return_val) {
      std::cout << "Invalid input!\n";
    }
  } while (!return_val);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic templating and simplify this code, which will be optimized and easier to read.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

enum Input1 { Type1 = 1, Type2 = 2, Type3 = 3, Type4 = 4};
enum Input2 { Type11 = 1, Type22 = 2};

bool validate_input(Input1 input1, Input2 input2 = Type11) {
    return (input1 >= Type1 && input1 <= Type4) && (input2 == Type11 || input2 == Type22);
}

template <typename T>
T get_valid_input(const std::string& prompt, const std::string& error_message = "Invalid input! Try again.") {
    T input;
    do {
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::cin >> input;

        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        } else {
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            return input;
        }

        std::cout << error_message << std::endl;
    } while (true);
}

int main() {
    Input1 eInput1;
    Input2 eInput2;

    eInput1 = get_valid_input<Input1>("Select option: 1, 2, 3 or 4:", "Invalid input for input1! Must be between 1 and 4.");

    eInput2 = get_valid_input<Input2>("Select option: 1 or 2:", "Invalid input for input2! Must be 1 or 2.");

    std::cout << "Valid inputs: " << static_cast<int>(eInput1) << ", " << static_cast<int>(eInput2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ashamedgap if you are happy with this solution, please up vote thanks!